# Visual Studio 2012 debug using different dll and pdb

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, crash-dumps

I am trying to open a dump file using Visual Studio 2012 but there are some PDB files missing.

Is there a way to make the debugger use another PDB file, built on my machine? 
Unfortunately, I can't access the original DLLs and PDBs.

I'm trying to open my PDBs using the "Browse and find ***.dll..." button but I'm getting an error message saying "a matching symbol file was not found in this folder"

Comment: It would be much easier if you had the dll's and pdb's that matched the dump file but maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744870/how-can-you-change-an-age-mismatched-pdb-to-match-properly

Comment: I suggest using wlndbg and issue .loadby sos clr

Comment: Everybody makes this mistake once.  Rebuild your app, preserve the DLLs and PDBs, and send it to your customer, along with an "I'm sorry".

Comment: And some companies make that mistakes for years

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated than that. I'm using a third-party that is using another third-party and the application crashes somewhere in the second third-party. So I tried to build the second third-party myself hoping to see where the crash occurs (It's an access violation exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio does not have an option to ignore mismatched symbols. Other debuggers (like WinDbg) have that.

[ChkMatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) is able to modify a PDB file so that Visual Studio does not recognize the difference any more. However, the result is what it is: even a slight modification might cause the compiler to emit totally different code. What you see in Visual Studio may be totally misleading. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27113605/480982) for details.

Be warned: delete the modified file immediately after your investigation or you will hunt ghost bugs sooner or later.